# Can I see what difficulty I am playing?

Tags: diablo-iii

Once I am in a game can I see what difficulty it is set to in any way without having to go kill something and see what level loot it drops?

Comment: @Flyto why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @z- if you look (s)he instead updated the old accepted answer.

Comment: he did that after literally 1 second after my comment lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of Diablo 2.0, this is no longer the case. The difficulty can be seen in the top right of the screen, next to the clock, while playing.

---

The only way I'm aware of is at the character select screen:

[image: Diablo 3 Character Select screen, with quest and difficulty highlighted]

You can change the difficulty (assuming you've unlocked them) by going to the Select Quest screen, and changing the difficulty of the quest you're going to start.

Comment: Also, pressing Escape displays a nice closeup of your character and a brief overview of the parameters of the game on the right.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like something that really should be able to be checked in-game, but after going though all of the menus and tooltips that I could think of, I'm concluding that no, it is not possible. The only way to check is by leaving the game (Esc -> Leave Game).