# How can you tell what difficulty the game you are in is set on?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I see what difficulty I am playing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68204/can-i-see-what-difficulty-i-am-playing)

When I join a friends game there, nowhere does it tell me in game or on the joining screen.

Is there any way to tell what difficulty the game is?